# How do I show that the two sequences below are short exact sequences of vector spaces?

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, galois-theory, finite-fields, exact-sequence

1. $0 \rightarrow \mathbb{Z_2}^k \to \mathbb{Z_2}^n \to \mathbb{Z_2}^{n-k} \to 0$
2. $0 \to \mathbb{Z_2} \to \mathbb{F}_{2^2} \to \mathbb{Z_2} \to 0$, where $\mathbb{F}_{2^2}$ is the Galois field of size $2^2$.

For the first, I have defined $\alpha : \mathbb{Z_2}^{k} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z_2}^n$ as $(a_1, \dots, a_k) \mapsto (0, \dots, 0, a_1, \dots a_k)$ and $\beta : \mathbb{Z_2}^n\to \mathbb{Z_2}^{n-k}$ as $(b_1, \dots, b_n) \mapsto (b_1, \dots, b_{n-k})$. Then $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are seen to be injective and surjective, respectively.

Further, $\beta (\alpha (\mathbb{Z_2}^k))=0$ so that $im(\alpha) \subset ker(\beta)$ and $b \in ker(\beta) \implies b\in im(\alpha)$ so that $im(\alpha)=ker(\beta)$. Is this correct?

Also, need help showing how the second is a short exact sequence.

Comment: What are the maps in 2.?

Comment: @JohnMa I don't know. They're not given. They weren't given for the first either.

Comment: So your question is really: Construct a short exact sequence between $\mathbb Z_2$, $\mathbb F_{2^2}$ and $\mathbb Z_2$ instead of "showing that the sequence is short exact".....

Comment: @JohnMa I asked this question exactly as is asked in the past papers. I'm not certain if that's what we should be doing, but only guessed so when trying to answer the first part.

Comment: HInt: rank-nullity theorem.

Comment: Note that 2 follows from 1 if you realize that $\mathbb F_{2^2}$ is a two dimensional $\mathbb Z_2$-vector space.

Comment: @JohnMa I see. Thank you for your help.